# Fixing: "There are no devices registered in your account" without a Lightning cable Xcode 11.0

Tags: xcode, lightning, code-signing

Using Xcode, when I try to sign my app, I get an error that says:

```
Failed to create provision profile
There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device 
to have Xcode register it
```

However, I *do* have my Mac registered on the website, which isn't showing up for some reason in Xcode. I don't have a USB-C lightning cable with me, which seems to be a direct requirement to connect my iPhone to my Mac.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Edit: There is a secondary error that says that no profile was found for my bundle ID, but I'm pretty sure this stems from the previously mentioned one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't have a USB-C lightning cable with me, which seems to be a direct requirement to connect my iPhone to my Mac.
>
> Is there any way to solve this issue?

You'd need to connect and pair your iPhone to your Mac at least once before you can perform wireless debugging.

If you do not have a USB-C to Lightning Cable cable, you'd need to either get one or use a USB-C to USB Adapter ([like this](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1M2AM/A/usb-c-to-usb-adapter)) or a similar hub.

The iPhone (or any iOS device) needs to be connected physically to the Mac and you'd have to manually [Trust the iOS device](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202778) before it could be paired with Xcode. This security reason is why you'd need a cable to connect the iPhone in the first place, and there is no way to work around it wirelessly.

> There is a secondary error that says that no profile was found for my bundle ID, but I'm pretty sure this stems from the previously mentioned one.

You can resolve this by going to Xcode Preferences → Accounts and add your Apple ID. If it is already added, you can try by removing and adding it again.

Comment: I had added my Apple ID again, and still it returns this error.

Comment: @12rhombiingridwnocorners After you manage to find a compatible cable/connector and connect the device, try building and running the app on device and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: So there is no way to fix this error without a compatible lightning cable then?

Comment: @12rhombiingridwnocorners Yes, at worst you need to have a cable to connect the iPhone physically to make progress.

Comment: It now says that it can't locate support files. My iPhone is running iOS 13.5.1, and my Xcode version is 11.3.1, the latest version for Mojave. What's going on here?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the message? Xcode 11.3.1 is the latest available for Mojave and it includes iOS 13.2 SDK.

Comment: yeah it includes the 13.2 sdk but it doesn't support iOS 13.5. i needed to paste over a 13.5 sdk from [this repo](https://github.com/haikieu/xcode-developer-disk-image-all-platforms/tree/master/DiskImages/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport). thanks ffor the help btw, i'm going to accept your answer because it does indeed appear you need a lightning cable for iOS developement. i don't like it, but hey. what can you do, right?

Comment: Is there a way to solve it without needed to iPhone? because I don't have one :\